# What is the best way to get a docker container to call itself via HTTP

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have dockerised app which produces HTML output on the fly. From within the container (not the host) I try to get the script to call itself via HTTP using its IP address and I always get back a connection timeout response.

What is the best way to get a docker container to call itself via HTTP.

Strict Rule: Unfortunately it has to be via HTTP.

## EDIT

```
<?php
// This is the call I need to perform.

if($htmlReport = file_get_contents('http://localhost/generate/report.php')) {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/fs/report.html', $htmlReport);
}
```

As you can see the script needs to call report.php. To clarify the script runs as a background process. Report.php cannot save the report due how the runtime deps are loaded (I inherited this project).

Comment: Could you explain/provide an example as to why it calls itself?

Comment: Did you try using `localhost:[container-port]` instead of ip address ?

Comment: `curl localhost`?

Comment: localhost should work if you are not using --net="host" when running the container

Comment: Please see my update